# How to search user in AD using powershell while skipping folders

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Current powershell script being used is in this format:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties EmailAddress, DisplayName -SearchBase "OU=USERS, OU=Site, OU=$_, DC=domain" -Server ServerName | Select DisplayNAme, EmailAddress
```

My problem is that the OU users, and site are buried in different folders one level up, and I can't figure out how to make the powershell script look thru all the folders above `(OU=$_)`. Using `OU=*` doesn't work either (bad syntax error).

Answer (score 0):

The `-SearchBase` parameter doesn't allow wildcards, if I understand correctly, you're looking for all parents OUs having `OU=USERS, OU=Site` as child OU, in which case, you can first filter for all OUs with **Name** `Users` then filter again for those OUs where their **DistinguishedName** contains `OU=USERS, OU=Site` and lastly feed these OUs to `Get-ADUser -SearchBase`:

```
(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter "(name=users)").DistinguishedName | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -notlike "OU=USERS, OU=Site*") { return }
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties EmailAddress, DisplayName -SearchBase $_ -Server ServerName
} | Select DisplayName, EmailAddress
```

Comment: It's not just the `-SearchBase` parameter; wildcards don't work on *any* field either that returns a `DistinuguishedName` with `-Filter`, either.

Comment: Active directory is set up as: domain folder/(multiple) type folder/(multiple) site folder/ (multiple) folders, one named user/user information. I'm trying to find information from all users within specific site regardless of type.